# Problem sending data from a UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am creating a stopwatch app that has a button for tracking each lap time. The problem I am having is sending the data from my UIViewController to UITableViewController.

All I have ever been able to find is how to send data from a UITableViewController to a ViewController, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
//Function to update the number of laps
@IBAction func newLapAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //Add 1 lap each time button is pressed
    laps += 1

    //Reset the Current Lap Counter
    currentTimeLabel.text = "00:00:00"
    (minutes, seconds, milliseconds) = (0, 0, 0)

    //Print updated lap # to screen
    numLapLabel.text = String(laps)
}
```

Here when the newLap button is pressed it should send the current time to a new lap in the TableViewController.

Comment: So... where's the reference to the `TableViewController`? We know nothing about the architecture of your app, and the code sample you've provided is non-specific to your question

Answer (score 0):

> That's pretty basic for UITableViewController.
>
> Just properly work with UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, You can easily achieve that.